# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\mybbeklents\rapor\gonder.php on line 11

Tags: php, mysql, email, post

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die (mysql_error());
$db  = mysql_select_db("mybbeklenti",$con)or die(mysql_error());

$ad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ad"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$mesaj = $_POST["mesaj"];
$kiriklink = $_POST["kiriklink"];

if($ad==""){header("location:index.php?kls=1");}else
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2")}else
{if($mesaj==""){header("location:index.php?kls=3")}else
{if($kiriklink==""){header("location:index.php?kls=4")}else
{mysql_query("INSERT INTO bildirim (`ad`,`email`,`acklama`,`kiriklink`,`tarih`) VALUES ('$ad','$email','$mesaj','$kiriklink',now())");header("location:index.php?kls=5");}}}}


?>
```

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\mybbeklents\rapor\gonder.php on line 11

1. Line is {if($email=="" line please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolons:

```
if($ad==""){header("location:index.php?kls=1");}else
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2");}else
{if($mesaj==""){header("location:index.php?kls=3");}else
{if($kiriklink==""){header("location:index.php?kls=4");}else
{mysql_query("INSERT INTO bildirim (`ad`,`email`,`acklama`,`kiriklink`,`tarih`) VALUES ('$ad','$email','$mesaj','$kiriklink',now())");header("location:index.php?kls=5");}}}}
```

Btw. if you don't use, then you should start using some IDE like netbeans or phpdesigner, it will show you where error is

NEW CODE:

```
if($ad==""){header("location:index.php?kls=1");}else
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2");}else
{if($mesaj==""){header("location:index.php?kls=3");}else
{if($kiriklink==""){header("location:index.php?kls=4");}else

{
    $query = "INSERT INTO bildirim (`ad`,`email`,`acklama`,`kiriklink`,`tarih`) 
    VALUES ('$ad','$email','$mesaj','$kiriklink',now())";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }   
    header("location:index.php?kls=5");


}}}}
```

Try this new code, there are few changes.

First is that you create query before is is sended to db, so if query don't work you can try it in phpmyadmin directly and find out if it is correct.
Second is that this code check if query was acomplished, if not it throw you error message and terminate program

and WARNING for you: stop using Mysql_* functions. They are deprecated. Start using Mysqli or PDO, they are much safer

Comment: There is no error but now its not save to mysql

Comment: answer edited with new code

Comment: You look like new here, so if someone helps you solve your problem in question, you may click at top left corner of aswer to accept it as good answer. If you have another question, create another question later, don't ask in the same

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `terminator(Semicolon)` --> `;`  at line `11,12,13`

```
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2");}else
                                                  ^Here
```

and SO on

Comment: There is no error but now its not save to mysq

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted the semi-colon on this line:

```
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2");}else
                                                  ^
```

and similarly on the next couple of lines.

Comment: There is no error but now its not save to mysql

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolon (;) following three lines

```
{if($email==""){header("location:index.php?kls=2");}else
                                                  ^ missing semicolon here
{if($mesaj==""){header("location:index.php?kls=3");}else
                                                  ^ missing semicolon here
{if($kiriklink==""){header("location:index.php?kls=4");}else
                                                      ^ missing semicolon here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons and have closed (you have put '}' after 'else' between every 'else if') the if condition in unnecessary place. And there are four '}' in last line unnecessarily. Check following code.

```
if($ad==""){
   header("location:index.php?kls=1");
}else if($email==""){
   header("location:index.php?kls=2"); 
}else if($mesaj==""){
   header("location:index.php?kls=3");
}else if($kiriklink==""){
   header("location:index.php?kls=4");
}else{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO bildirim (`ad`,`email`,`acklama`,`kiriklink`,`tarih`) VALUES ('$ad','$email','$mesaj','$kiriklink',now())");
   header("location:index.php?kls=5");
}
```